# Java Profiling For Runnable jar

Tags: java, performance, profiling

I have a developed a application in java, I executing it using the runnable jar version.

I inspected the cpu consumption level and memory consumption level in the task manager in windows. It uses half of cpu and half of memory. Is there are any way to find how much acutal memory and cpu cycles consumed in the application level for each classes and so on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called VisualVM that will give you very detailed profiling information. Check it out here: http://visualvm.java.net/